# Help with system of linear equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am in need of help solving for $x$ and $y$.

$$
\begin{cases} 10x-8y=-5x
\\
5x=4y-20 
\end{cases}
$$

I've tried but don't really get what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! We also don't get what you're doing wrong, if you let us know what you tried then we can try to find any mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** throw everything with letters to one side, and lonely numbers to the other: $$\begin{cases} \mathbb {(i)} \quad 10x + 5x -8y = 0  \\ \mathbb {(ii)} \quad 5x - 4y = -20 \end{cases}$$

Look at $\mathbb{(i)} - 2\mathbb{(ii)}$ to find $x$. Then choose whatever equation you like and substitute the value of $x$ you just found, to solve for $y$.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to extract $x$ from the first equation and then to replace it in the second. From the first one get $10x+5x=8y$ then $15x=8y$ so $x=8y/15$. Now, in the second equation we replace $x$ by $8y/15$, that is $5(8y/15)=4y-20$, then $8y/3=4y-20$ then $8y/3-4y=-20$ so $8y/3-12y/3=-20$ or $-4y/3=-20$ cross product gives $-4y=-60$ finaly $y=15$. Now we go back to $x=8y/15$ and we replace $y$ by $15$, we get $x=8*15/15=8$. Therefore, $x=8$ and $y=15$.

Comment: That's a similar way that I did, I got confused on the way because I had no idea what I was doing. Isn't the x already = 8y/15? Why do we need to calculate the second part, and then go back to the first one again? I mean isn't the x just = 8y/15?

Comment: yes x=8y/15 but you do not know the value of y!!! so we plug the expression of x with respect to y (which is 8y/15) in the second equation and simplifying we obtain the value of y which is a number completely known, and then we replace y by this number in 8y/15 to obtain x as a number comletely known.

Comment: if i tell you that your mark will be the double of John's mark it is not clear because you do not know john's mark but if I tell you that you will get 95% this is clear! Ok?